# Postgresql init.d script not working

Tags: ubuntu, database, vps, postgresql

I installed Postgresql 8.4 on my VPS with Ubuntu 10.04. Default setup, nothing unusual. After the installation the dbserver is automatically started and is running great. The installer also sets a init.d script in place.

This script however, doesn't seem to affect Postgres.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
```

The above line is not stopping the server. The command does not fail or show any message. The logs won't say anything as well.

After killing all postgres processes with killall I cannot get Postgres working again using the init script. When rebooting my VPS it somehow starts up and works again.

Update:

This is what happens when I strace the stop command:

```
01:13:29.074927 close(6)                = 0 <0.000079>
01:13:29.075215 fcntl64(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0 <0.000040>
01:13:29.075554 dup2(5, 1)               = 1 <0.000073>
01:13:29.075778 close(5)                = 0 <0.000075>
01:13:29.075977 close(4)                = 0 <0.000054>
01:13:29.076309 rt_sigaction(SIGFPE, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN, [FPE], SA_RESTART}, 8) = 0 <0.000080>
01:13:29.076597 execve("/bin/ps", ["/bin/ps", "-o", "comm", "h", "p", "3986"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0 <0.000798>
01:13:29.077667 brk(0)                  = 0x87de000 <0.000775>
01:13:29.078611 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000095>
01:13:29.078851 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)         = 0xb774f000 <0.000043>
01:13:29.078996 mmap2(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb774c000 <0.000043>
01:13:29.079203 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000240>
01:13:29.079660 open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000145>
01:13:29.080038 fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=25991, ...}) = 0 <0.000098>
01:13:29.080273 mmap2(NULL, 25991, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb7745000 <0.000073>
01:13:29.080440 close(3) = 0 <0.000164>
01:13:29.080701 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000074>
01:13:29.080909 open("/lib/libproc-3.2.8.so", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000065>
01:13:29.081067 read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0`(\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512 <0.000048>
01:13:29.081254 fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=59140, ...}) = 0 <0.000034>
01:13:29.081437 mmap2(NULL, 136568, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb7723000 <0.000042>
01:13:29.081575 mmap2(0xb7731000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xd) = 0xb7731000 <0.000047>
01:13:29.081738 mmap2(0xb7733000, 71032, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7733000 <0.000034>
01:13:29.081905 close(3)                = 0 <0.000040>
01:13:29.082055 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000059>
01:13:29.082241 open("/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000052>
01:13:29.082413 read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0000m\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512 <0.000052>
01:13:29.082593 fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1430084, ...}) = 0 <0.000041>
01:13:29.082783 mmap2(NULL, 1436072, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb75c4000 <0.000046>
01:13:29.082933 mmap2(0xb771d000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x159) = 0xb771d000 <0.000047>
01:13:29.083099 mmap2(0xb7720000, 10664, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7720000 <0.000051>
01:13:29.083274 close(3)                = 0 <0.000045>
01:13:29.083458 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb75c3000 <0.000047>
01:13:29.083617 set_thread_area({entry_number:-1 -> 6, base_addr:0xb75c38d0, limit:1048575, seg_32bit:1, contents:0, read_exec_only:0, limit_in_pages:1, seg_not_present:0, useable:1}) = 0 <0.000102>
01:13:29.084004 mprotect(0xb771d000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0 <0.000051>
01:13:29.084181 mprotect(0xb7731000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 <0.000042>
01:13:29.084331 mprotect(0x805a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 <0.000044>
01:13:29.084481 mprotect(0xb776b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 <0.000053>
01:13:29.084624 munmap(0xb7745000, 25991) = 0 <0.000069>
01:13:29.084981 brk(0)                  = 0x87de000 <0.000041>
01:13:29.085118 brk(0x87ff000)          = 0x87ff000 <0.000042>
01:13:29.085300 open("/proc/version", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000067>
01:13:29.085517 fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 <0.000040>
01:13:29.085700 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb774b000 <0.000043>
01:13:29.085828 read(3, "Linux version 3.5.2-linode45 (ma"..., 1024) = 117 <0.000054>
01:13:29.086005 close(3)                = 0 <0.000061>
01:13:29.086164 munmap(0xb774b000, 4096) = 0 <0.000065>
01:13:29.086451 open("/proc/stat", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000042>
01:13:29.086595 read(3, "cpu  27600 1973 16641 13435954 4"..., 8192) = 556 <0.000060>
01:13:29.086750 close(3)                = 0 <0.000031>
01:13:29.086934 open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000049>
01:13:29.087113 open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000052>
01:13:29.087276 fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2570, ...}) = 0 <0.000049>
01:13:29.087467 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb774b000 <0.000045>
01:13:29.087609 read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2570 <0.000066>
01:13:29.087854 read(3, "", 4096)       = 0 <0.000051>
01:13:29.088002 close(3)                = 0 <0.000043>
01:13:29.088136 munmap(0xb774b000, 4096) = 0 <0.000053>
01:13:29.088394 open("/usr/lib/locale/nl_NL.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000050>
01:13:29.088568 open("/usr/lib/locale/nl_NL.utf8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000047>
01:13:29.088719 fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=256324, ...}) = 0 <0.000042>
01:13:29.088901 mmap2(NULL, 256324, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb7584000 <0.000045>
01:13:29.089035 close(3)                = 0 <0.000043>
01:13:29.089205 open("/usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000048>
01:13:29.089368 fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26048, ...}) = 0 <0.000042>
01:13:29.089552 mmap2(NULL, 26048, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0xb7745000 <0.000037>
01:13:29.089673 close(3)                = 0 <0.000028>
01:13:29.089825 rt_sigaction(SIGSYS, {0x80494d4, ~[RTMIN RT_1], 0}, NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000036>
01:13:29.089973 rt_sigaction(SIGPWR, {0x80494d4, ~[RTMIN RT_1], 0}, NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000030>
01:13:29.090103 rt_sigaction(SIGIO, {0x80494d4, ~[RTMIN RT_1], 0}, NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000029>
01:13:29.090233 rt_sigaction(SIGVTALRM, {0x80494d4, ~[RTMIN RT_1], 0}, NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000030>
01:13:29.090356 rt_sigaction(SIGXFSZ, {0x80494d4, ~[RTMIN RT_1], 0}, NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000031>
01:13:29.090486 rt_sigaction(SIGXCPU, {0x80494d4, ~[RTMIN RT_1], 0}, NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000030>

Blablablablalbs

01:13:29.199744 open("/proc/4028/stat", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000052>
01:13:29.199936 read(6, "4028 (postgres) S 3986 4028 4028"..., 1023) = 280 <0.000054>
01:13:29.200112 close(6)                = 0 <0.000051>
01:13:29.200272 open("/proc/4028/status", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000045>
01:13:29.200423 read(6, "Name:\tpostgres\nState:\tS (sleepin"..., 1023) = 767 <0.000064>
01:13:29.200595 close(6)                = 0 <0.000035>
01:13:29.200734 stat64("/proc/4192", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 <0.000052>
01:13:29.200945 open("/proc/4192/stat", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000046>
01:13:29.201101 read(6, "4192 (ruby) S 1 2768 2765 0 -1 4"..., 1023) = 282 <0.000046>
01:13:29.201264 close(6)                = 0 <0.000049>
01:13:29.201428 open("/proc/4192/status", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000064>
01:13:29.201604 read(6, "Name:\truby\nState:\tS (sleeping)\nT"..., 1023) = 763 <0.000069>
01:13:29.201774 close(6)                = 0 <0.000052>
01:13:29.201926 stat64("/proc/6207", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 <0.000046>
01:13:29.202128 open("/proc/6207/stat", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000045>
01:13:29.202284 read(6, "6207 (ruby) S 1 2768 2765 0 -1 4"..., 1023) = 287 <0.000056>
01:13:29.202472 close(6)                = 0 <0.000039>
01:13:29.202624 open("/proc/6207/status", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000056>
01:13:29.202803 read(6, "Name:\truby\nState:\tS (sleeping)\nT"..., 1023) = 765 <0.000106>
01:13:29.203017 close(6)                = 0 <0.000040>
01:13:29.203187 stat64("/proc/8008", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 <0.000061>
01:13:29.203408 open("/proc/8008/stat", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000069>
01:13:29.203574 read(6, "8008 (ruby) S 1 2768 2765 0 -1 4"..., 1023) = 286 <0.000037>
01:13:29.203695 close(6)                = 0 <0.000044>
01:13:29.203844 open("/proc/8008/status", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000049>
01:13:29.203994 read(6, "Name:\truby\nState:\tS (sleeping)\nT"..., 1023) = 762 <0.000071>
01:13:29.204172 close(6)                = 0 <0.000059>
01:13:29.204355 stat64("/proc/10935", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 <0.000054>
01:13:29.204570 open("/proc/10935/stat", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000060>
01:13:29.204766 read(6, "10935 (pickup) S 2310 2310 2310 "..., 1023) = 276 <0.000070>
01:13:29.204967 close(6)                = 0 <0.000052>
01:13:29.205151 open("/proc/10935/status", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000045>
01:13:29.205303 read(6, "Name:\tpickup\nState:\tS (sleeping)"..., 1023) = 762 <0.000093>
01:13:29.205512 close(6)                = 0 <0.000085>
01:13:29.205717 stat64("/proc/11740", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 <0.000065>
01:13:29.205933 open("/proc/11740/stat", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000051>
01:13:29.206079 read(6, "11740 (sshd) S 2034 11740 11740 "..., 1023) = 278 <0.000064>
01:13:29.206244 close(6)                = 0 <0.000048>
01:13:29.206502 open("/proc/11740/status", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000045>
01:13:29.206654 read(6, "Name:\tsshd\nState:\tS (sleeping)\nT"..., 1023) = 743 <0.000081>
01:13:29.206831 close(6)                = 0 <0.000050>
01:13:29.207001 stat64("/proc/11813", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 <0.000057>
01:13:29.207228 open("/proc/11813/stat", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000058>
01:13:29.207434 read(6, "11813 (sshd) S 11740 11740 11740"..., 1023) = 275 <0.000061>
01:13:29.207604 close(6)                = 0 <0.000040>
01:13:29.207799 open("/proc/11813/status", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000048>
01:13:29.207966 read(6, "Name:\tsshd\nState:\tS (sleeping)\nT"..., 1023) = 774 <0.000079>
01:13:29.208164 close(6)                = 0 <0.000049>
01:13:29.208322 stat64("/proc/11814", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 <0.000060>
01:13:29.208553 open("/proc/11814/stat", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000065>
01:13:29.208731 read(6, "11814 (bash) S 11813 11814 11814"..., 1023) = 299 <0.000061>
01:13:29.208948 close(6)                = 0 <0.000055>
01:13:29.209137 open("/proc/11814/status", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000112>
01:13:29.209383 read(6, "Name:\tbash\nState:\tS (sleeping)\nT"..., 1023) = 774 <0.000071>
01:13:29.209597 close(6)                = 0 <0.000043>
01:13:29.209754 stat64("/proc/12139", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 <0.000049>
01:13:29.209948 open("/proc/12139/stat", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000068>
01:13:29.210127 read(6, "12139 (strace) S 11814 12139 118"..., 1023) = 278 <0.000060>
01:13:29.210300 close(6)                = 0 <0.000043>
01:13:29.210448 open("/proc/12139/status", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000063>
01:13:29.210636 read(6, "Name:\tstrace\nState:\tS (sleeping)"..., 1023) = 748 <0.000085>
01:13:29.210830 close(6)                = 0 <0.000035>
01:13:29.210958 stat64("/proc/12141", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 <0.000044>
01:13:29.211154 open("/proc/12141/stat", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000049>
01:13:29.211301 read(6, "12141 (postgresql) S 12139 12139"..., 1023) = 277 <0.000053>
01:13:29.211453 close(6)                = 0 <0.000058>
01:13:29.211618 open("/proc/12141/status", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000053>
01:13:29.211771 read(6, "Name:\tpostgresql\nState:\tS (sleep"..., 1023) = 754 <0.000068>
01:13:29.211956 close(6)                = 0 <0.000043>
01:13:29.212108 stat64("/proc/12143", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 <0.000071>
01:13:29.212358 open("/proc/12143/stat", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000085>
01:13:29.212597 read(6, "12143 (pg_lsclusters) S 12141 12"..., 1023) = 281 <0.000075>
01:13:29.212796 close(6)                = 0 <0.000050>
01:13:29.212982 open("/proc/12143/status", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000062>
01:13:29.213213 read(6, "Name:\tpg_lsclusters\nState:\tS (sl"..., 1023) = 758 <0.000081>
01:13:29.213437 close(6)                = 0 <0.000050>
01:13:29.213615 stat64("/proc/12144", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 <0.000079>
01:13:29.213866 open("/proc/12144/stat", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000058>
01:13:29.214025 read(6, "12144 (ps) R 12143 12139 11814 3"..., 1023) = 276 <0.000047>
01:13:29.214220 close(6)                = 0 <0.000049>
01:13:29.214390 open("/proc/12144/status", O_RDONLY) = 6 <0.000073>
01:13:29.214578 read(6, "Name:\tps\nState:\tR (running)\nTgid"..., 1023) = 746 <0.000070>
01:13:29.214768 close(6)                = 0 <0.000037>
01:13:29.214911 getdents(5, /* 0 entries */, 32768) = 0 <0.000048>
01:13:29.215055 close(5)                = 0 <0.000048>
01:13:29.215219 write(1, "postgres\n", 9) = 9 <0.000078>
01:13:29.215418 exit_group(0)           = ?
```

Comment: Can you strace the command. Like strace -ffttTo /tmp/strace.out <command name> and then pastebin the /tmp/strace.out files.

Comment: See edit I placed.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what kind of system you are on, however, **service postgresql stop** or **/usr/bin/pg_ctl stop** might work